# Who are the Chatur Bhaginyadinis mentioned by Adi Shankaracharya?

Tags: gods, bhagavad-gita, adi-shankaracharya, shaktism

In [chapter 9 verse 25](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/9/25) of the Bhagavad Gita, Krishna says this:

> yānti dēvavratā dēvān pitṛnyānti pitṛvratāḥ | 
> bhūtāni yānti bhūtējyā yānti madyājinō.pi mām৷৷
>
> Those who worship the demigods will take birth among the demigods; those who worship the ancestors go to the ancestors; those who worship ghosts and spirits will take birth among such beings; and those who worship Me will live with Me.

[Here](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-9-25/) is what Adi Shankaracharya says in his Bhagavad Gita Bhashya:

> Deva-vratah, votaries of the gods, those whose religious observances [Making offerings and presents, circumambulation, bowing down, etc.] and devotion are directed to the gods; yanti, reach, go to; devan, the gods. Pitr-vratah, the votaries of the manes, those who are occupied with such rites as obsequies etc., who are devoted to the manes; go pitrn, to the manes such as Agnisvatta and others. **Bhutejyah, the Beings such as Vinayaka, the group of Sixteen (divine) Mothers, the Four Sisters, and others**. And madyajinah, those who worship Me, those who are given to worshipping Me, the devotees of Visnu; reach mam, Me alone.
>
> yānti gacchanti dēvavratāḥdēvēṣu vrataṅ niyamō bhaktiśca yēṣāṅ tē dēvavratāḥ dēvān yānti | 
> pitṛn agniṣvāttādīn yānti pitṛvratāḥ śrāddhādikriyāparāḥ pitṛbhaktāḥ | 
>  **bhūtānivināyakamātṛgaṇacaturbhaginyādīni** yānti bhūtējyāḥ bhūtānāṅ pūjakāḥ | 
>  yānti madyājinaḥ madyajanaśīlāḥ vaiṣṇavāḥ māmēva yānti |

I'm interested in the part in bold.  Some of these figures are recognizable; you have Ganesha and you have the [Matrikas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrikas), a group of goddesses worshiped by Shaktas.  But my question is, who are the "Chatur Bhaginyadinis" or Four Sisters mentioned by Adi Shankaracharya?

Are they Shakta goddesses as well?

Comment: You are giving a whole lot of wrong information.---  and you have the Matrikas, a group of goddesses worshiped by Shaktas.---- The Matrikas are not only to be worshipped by the Shaktas . The worship of Deties like Ganapaty and Shodasha Matrikas are prescribed in the Smritis only as to be done compulsorily before any Vedic rituals.

Comment: @Rickross I don't know how I could be giving a "whole lot" of wrong information if most of my question just consists of quotes.  In any case, regardless of whether you believe they should be worshiped, as a practical matter the Matrikas aren't worshiped by Sri Vaishnavas, Gaudiya Vaishnavas, Shaiva Siddhantins, etc.

Comment: I am quoting ur text only not the BQs. And as i have said, Shodasha Matrikas are to be worshipped before any Vedic rituals. It's prescribed in Smritis only just like worship of Mahaganapty.. Also, don't talk about sects, as u do not belong to any of them yet (by initiation) so you can not really know what's really happening there.

Comment: @Rickross It's perfectly possible to talk about sects to which I don't belong, by reading their works, talking to their members, etc.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72088/discussion-on-question-by-keshav-srinivasan-who-are-the-four-sisters-mentioned-b).

Comment: There is translation problem in above quote. "bhūtānivināyakamātṛgaṇacaturbhaginyādīni"Adi Shankara was saying worshiping Ganas of Matrikas (not matrikas) and also Vinayakas (not Shiva's son Vinayaka). Refer translation by A Mahadeva Sastri. https://archive.org/details/Bhagavad-Gita.with.the.Commentary.of.Sri.Shankaracharya

Comment: @TheDestroyer I think Shiva's son Ganesha is one of the Vinayakas - there are Puranic passages regarding this.  But regardless, do you know anything about the Chatur Bhaginyadinis?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan There are many Vinayakas (ganas) who look like Shiva's son Vinayaka. And these Bhaginis are ganas of Matrikas. Whole passage refers to supporting ganas of main deities. In any case, i'm searching info for these Bhaginis.

Comment: @TheDestroyer By the way, the translation I quoted is by an Advaitin Sanyasi, Swami Gambhirananda, so it may be more reliable than the other translation which is by an Indologist.

Comment: It's Bhagini-Aadini (and others) not Bhaginyadinis. Is this the only place Shankaracharya mentions them?

Comment: @Surya Yeah, I can't find another reference to them in his Bhagavad Gita Bhashya.  But I found another reference to the Matrikas in his commentary on Gita verse 17.4: "Sattvikah, those having the sattva quality, those steadfast in sattva; yajante, worship; devan, the gods; rajasah, those having rajas; (worship) yaksa-raksamsi, the demi-gods and ogres; and anye, other; janah, people; tamasah, possessed of tamas; yajante, worship; pretan, ghosts; and bhuta-ganan, the hosts of spirits-Sapta-matrkas (the Seven Mothers) and others."